# How to determine between a string and an integer received from JSON in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I receive a result from JSONrequest where one attribute is normally a string but unfortunately sometimes is 0 (not a string). In order to process the JSON result I would like to check on whether it is a 0 or a string to avoid a crash

part of the JSON result:

```
"9919ee1e-ffbc-480b-bc4b-77fb047e9e68" =         {
        icon = home;
        id = "9919ee1e-ffbc-480b-bc4b-77fb047e9e68";
        index = 1;
        name = Thuis;
        parent = 0;
    };
    "9eb2975d-49ea-4033-8db0-105a3e982117" =         {
        icon = books;
        id = "9eb2975d-49ea-4033-8db0-105a3e982117";
        index = 6;
        name = Studeerkamer;
        parent = "9919ee1e-ffbc-480b-bc4b-77fb047e9e68";
    };
    "a4a23044-edce-4b81-be7f-a2123e14d8c0" =         {
        icon = kitchen;
        id = "a4a23044-edce-4b81-be7f-a2123e14d8c0";
        index = 1;
        name = Keuken;
        parent = "855113f1-f488-4223-b675-2f01270f573e";
    };
```

Notice the parent attribute, which is the attribute I am referring to. If somebody can help to point me in the right direction I would be very greatful, I am a beginner in Swift and Xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Parsing this JSON you can implemented a check like this to avoid crash and to parse data from JSON is

```
var parent:String?

if let parentId = dict.value(forKey:"parent") as? Int {
    parent = "\(parentId)"
} else if let parentId = dict.value(forKey:"parent") as? String {
   parent =  parentId
}
```

With this **parent variable** will have string value while it will be a 0(Int) or a key(String) received from JOSN.

Comment: Great this did the trick, just had to extend the check with another else if for Bool (as it turned out it was Boolean). Thanks very much

Comment: Yes, you can extend for all dataType which can be received in JSON.  Also upvote to answer is much better way to say thanks here.

Comment: I am sorry I gave you the upvote, but as a newbe without the reputation of 15 it will not show on the page, still I believe you will receive it

Answer (score 0):

check with `as?` keyword.

```
let index = record.value(forKey:"index") as? Int ?? -1
let id = record.value(forKey:"id") as? Int ?? "dummy value"
```

Comment: How is this a check ? How can I determine value that value["parent"] is an integer or a string without letting the app crash?